# create an ascii progress bar

Tags: code-golf, printable-ascii

well, it's something similar to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/) but with a little differences. you have to write a program to ask for width of progress bar and how much work is done. and then draw a progress bar with following features:

- width indicates how many characters you have to use to draw progress bar
- progress is given via a floating point value between 0..1.
- first and last character in progress bar should be something different from all other character, for example "[" and "]"
- your program should use two different characters to how much progress passed since the start
- you have to write how much work is done right in the middle of progress bar, using a decimal number + "%" sign.

**bonus point** for handling extreme inputs, such as 150% or -5% work done.

**scoring** number of characters * (1 without bonus or 0.75 width bonus)

**some examples of valid outputs**

```
79 0.15
[||||||||||||                         15%                                     ]
```

---

```
25 0.76
[##########76%#####.....]
```

---

```
39 -0.12
[                 -12%                 ]
```

---

```
25 7.6
[##########760%#########]
```

Comment: How is input taken? Command line? Stdin? Any of the above?

Comment: @lochok I guess stdin would be a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PHP 84 x 0.75 = 63

Edit: A less 'pretty' version, but it should be valid according to the rules:

```
[<?=str_pad(!fscanf(STDIN,~Ú›Ú™,$a,$b),$a*min(1,$b),~ß)|str_pad(100*$b.~Ú,$a,_,2)?>]
```

Output:

```
$ echo 79 0.15 | php progress-bar.php
[⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂___________________________15%______________________________________]
$ echo 25 0.76 | php progress-bar.php
[⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂76%⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂______]
$ echo 39 -0.12 | php progress-bar.php
[_________________-12%__________________]
$ echo 25 7.6 | php progress-bar.php
[⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂760%⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂]
```

#### Original (98 x 0.75 = 73.5)

```
[<?=strtr(str_pad(!fscanf(STDIN,~Ú›Ú™,$a,$b),$a*min(1,$b),~ß)|str_pad(100*$b.~Ú,$a,~ü,2),~ü,~ß)?>]
```

Output:

```
$ echo 79 0.15 | php progress-bar.php
[###########                           15%                                      ]
$ echo 25 0.76 | php progress-bar.php
[###########76%#####      ]
$ echo 39 -0.12 | php progress-bar.php
[                 -12%                  ]
$ echo 25 7.6 | php progress-bar.php
[##########760%###########]
```

Comment: I'm wondering how can I run your code.

Comment: Save it as a php file. Send it the two paramaters as a space separated string as STDIN. For example:

[windows/linux command prompt] echo 79 0.15 | php progress-bar.php

You will need to have the php-cli (command line interface) installed. Most php installers for windows should have it included (or optional), linux with apt-get install php5-cli

Comment: I've selected this answer since as far as I tested this one always worked as expected, while one that ephemient provided sometimes doesn't print the number exactly in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

## J, 78×0.75 = 58.5

```
'w p'=:_".1!:1]3
1!:2&4('%',~":100*p)(i.@[-<.@-:@-)&#}'[]'0 _1}' |'{~(w*p)>i.w
```

```
$ echo -n 79 0.15 | jconsole test.ijs
[|||||||||||                          15%                                     ]
$ echo -n 25 0.76 | jconsole test.ijs
[||||||||||76%|||||     ]   
$ echo -n 39 -0.12
[                 _12%                ]
$ echo -n 25 7.6 | jconsole test.ijs
[|||||||||760%||||||||||]
```

(Negative numbers in J are prefixed by `_`, not `-`.  Luckily, dyadic `".` can parse both formats.)

Comment: Does this exclude the space taken by the percentage when it calculates the number of bars to display? Cause it seems to get different results from mine.

Comment: @grc With 100 columns, each percent is a single bar (even if hidden by other elements such as the brackets or number/percent).

Comment: Okay I get it now. Good job :)

Comment: @ephemient now I've noticed in -0.12 case, you are printing 18 spaces at left part and 16 at right part. it means `_12%` is not exactly in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 96×¾ = 72

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -ap
formline'[@'.'|'x($F[0]-3).']',100*$F[1].'%';
$_=$^A;s# |(.)#$1//($-[0]<$F[0]*$F[1]?'|':$&)#eg
```

That's by traditional Perl golf rules (`#!` line not counted, except for the `-` and switches if any).

```
$ echo 79 0.15 | perl test.pl
[|||||||||||                          15%                                     ]
$ echo 25 0.76 | perl test.pl
[||||||||||76%|||||     ]
$ echo 39 -0.12 | perl test.pl
[                -12%                 ]
$ echo 25 7.6 | perl test.pl
[|||||||||760%||||||||||]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python - <strike>158</strike> <strike>155</strike> <strike>148</strike> <strike>143</strike> 138 characters (score of 103.5)

```
x,y=raw_input().split()
x=int(x)-2
y=float(y)
p=`int(y*100)`+"%"
b="|"*int(x*y+.5)+" "*x
print"["+b[:(x-len(p))/2]+p+b[(x+len(p))/2:x]+"]"
```

It could be 30 characters shorter if the input was separated by a comma.

Comment: why didn't you use `r=p.length()`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: nothing my bad, I just misunderstood you code.

Comment: but your code doesn't seem to handle -12% case.

Comment: What is it meant to do? At the moment it just prints an empty bar with the percentage.

Comment: nope, note that with y being way negative, r will also be something below zero, and that will break his code.

Comment: Multiplying strings by negative numbers just returns and empty string.

Comment: you changed his code, it was wrong before you change it!

Comment: I've been shortening it, but it has worked for me each time. Check the revision history of the post if you want.

Answer (score 2):

#### Ruby - score 93 (124 characters)

```
w=gets.to_i-2
f=$_[/ .+/].to_f
e=f<0?0:f>1?w:(f*w).to_i
b='#'*e+' '*(w-e)
b[(w-l=(s='%d%'%(100*f)).size)/2,l]=s
puts"[#{b}]"
```

Yet another ruby implementation. Reads input from STDIN in the form described above. You may exchange characters `'#'`, `' '` and `'['`, `']'` directly in the code.

```
45 0.88
[####################88%##############      ]

60 1.22
[###########################122%###########################]
```

Comment: this is alway two chars too wide

Comment: @padde Why do you think it's two chars too wide? There is a -2 in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala 149:

```
val w=readInt 
val p=readFloat
println(("["+"|"*(p*w).toInt+" "*((w-p*w).toInt)+"]").replaceAll("(^.{"+(w/2-3)+"}).{5}","$1 "+(p*100).toInt+("% ")))
```

ungolfed:

```
def progressbar (width: Int, pos: Double) {
  println ((
    "["+
    "|"*(pos*width).toInt+
    " "*((width-pos*width).toInt)+
    "]").
    replaceAll ("(^.{" + (width/2-3) + "}).{5}", "$1 " + (p * 100).toInt + ("% ")))}
}
```

I decided, for readability, you really need a space around the progress number:

```
(44 to 54).map (x => b (100, x/100.0))
[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||   44%                                                  ]
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||  45%                                                  ]
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 46%                                                  ]
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 47%                                                  ]
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 48%                                                  ]
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 49%                                                  ]
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 50%                                                  ]
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 51%                                                  ]
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 52% |                                                ]
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 53% ||                                               ]
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 54% |||                                              ]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Q,90 chars, no bonus

```
{-1 @[x#" ";(1+(!)(_)x*y;0;((_)x%2)+(!)(#)($)a;x-1);:;("|";"[";a:,[;"%"]($)(100*y);"]")];}
```

usage

```
q){-1 @[x#" ";(1+(!)(_)x*y;0;((_)x%2)+(!)(#)($)a;x-1);:;("|";"[";a:,[;"%"]($)(100*y);"]")];}[50;0.15]
[|||||||                 15%                     ]

q){-1 @[x#" ";(1+(!)(_)x*y;0;((_)x%2)+(!)(#)($)a;x-1);:;("|";"[";a:,[;"%"]($)(100*y);"]")];}[30;0.35]
[||||||||||    35%           ]

q){-1 @[x#" ";(1+(!)(_)x*y;0;((_)x%2)+(!)(#)($)a;x-1);:;("|";"[";a:,[;"%"]($)(100*y);"]")];}[40;0.85]
[|||||||||||||||||||85%||||||||||||    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 145 characters, score = 108.75

```
float p;s;m;char x[99];main(){scanf("%d%f",&s,&p);sprintf(x+s/2-1,"%.0f%%",p*100);for(;m<s;)x[++m]||(x[m]=m<p*s?35:32);x[s-1]=93;*x=91;puts(x);}
```

Comment: though I really liked your idea of sprintf, but it generates a minor problem, check your program with `20 1` inputs it will generate output of `[#######100%######]` in this case there are 7 sharps left of number and 5 sharps at right, so the number printed is not exactly in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript <del>127</del> 125, no bonus

```
l=9,p="0.99",f=l*p|0,m=l/2|0,x=["]"];for(;l--;)x.unshift(l>=f?"-":"+");x[m++]=p[2],x[m++]=p[3],x[m]="%";alert("["+x.join(""))
//[+++99%++-]
```

**Usage:** Change `l=9` with other *length* and/or change `p="0.99"` with other *percent*

<sub>**Note:** end with zero `0.X0` instead of `0.X`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### PHP-128x0.75=>96

```
<?fscanf(STDIN,'%d%d',$w,$p);$v='[';for($i=1;$i<$w-1;)$v.=($i++==$w/2-1)?$p*($i+=2)/$i.'%':(($i<$w*$p/100)?'|':' ');echo"$v]";?>
```

```
<?fscanf(STDIN,'%d%f',$w,$p);$v='[';for($i=1;$i<$w-1;)$v.=($i++==$w/2-1)?$p*100*($i+=2)/$i.'%':(($i<$w*$p)?'|':' ');echo"$v]";?>
```

### C, 149*0.75=111.75

```
main(w,i){float p;for(i=printf("[",scanf("%d%f",&w,&p));i<w-1;)(i++==w/2-1)?printf("%.0f%%",p*100*(i+=2)/i):printf("%c",i<=(p*w)?'|':' ');puts("]");}
```

Output:

```
80
0.75
[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||75%||||||||||||||||||                   ]

80
7.60
[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||760%|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||]


80
-0.12
[                                      -12%                                     ]
```

Comment: p should be a floating point value, between 0..1

Comment: @Gajet thanks for bringing to notice. Has been rectified :)

Answer (score 1):

node.js: 135chars, *0.75 for bonus points, so 101.25chars.

```
a=process.argv,i=a[2],p=a[3],o=i/2|0,f=i-i*p,x=['['];for(;i--;){x.push((i<f?' ':'|')+(i-o?'':p*100+'%'));}console.log(x.join('')+']');
```

ungolfed:

```
a = process.argv, // console inputs
i = a[2], // input 1 -> width
p = a[3], // input 2 -> percent complete
o = i / 2 | 0, // half of i, without any decimal places
f = i - i * p, // how far along the bar to draw spaces
x = ['[']; // start an array
while(i--){ // while i > 0
    x.push( // add to the array
    (i < f ? ' ' : '|') // a space, or | depending on how far along the bar we are
    + (i - o ? '' : p * 100 + '%')); // and if we're halfway, add the percentage complete
}
console.log(x.join('') + ']'); // then write out the array as a string, with a trailing ]
```

output:

```
D:\mercurial\golf\ascii>node progressBar.js 25 7.6
[|||||||||||||760%||||||||||||]

D:\mercurial\golf\ascii>node progressBar.js 39 -0.12
[                    -12%                   ]

D:\mercurial\golf\ascii>node progressBar.js 79 0.15
[|||||||||||                             15%                                       ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), score 35.25 (47 * 0.75)

```
qqtl&O61bti*Xl:(HG100*V37hyn2/kyny+q&:(91w93v!c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchNC4IwGADg@37F2yERI3OKjnkO2i2ECI@ZKMrm/Nhrtl@/7PTAM1So3MvNMyrvntE39kGpcl/caBQFz4R1VscXabU9zV7uc7rx5HOonSiKUnzhCF1VS8ARhko20CNs4yKhHRcYVoX9pPbU04qAjUEwDRpyfTjGSRTSlMTpLstIwsl5j/gfLMx@)

#### Explanation:

```
         % implicit input, say w = 79
qq       % decrement input by 2 (to allow brackets on either side)
tl&O     % duplicate and create array with that many zeros
61       % Push '=' character
b        % bubble up w-2 from below
ti*      % duplicate and multiply by second input, say p = 0.15
         %  stack: [[0;0;0;...;0], 61, 77, 11.55]
Xl       % take minimum of (w-2) and (w-2)*p
         %  (used when p > 1, makes eligible for bonus)
:        % create range 1 to that value 
         %  stack: [[0;0;0;...;0], 61, [1 2 3 4 5 ... 11]]
(        % assign into the first array the value 61 ('=') at the 
         %  indices denoted by the third array
HG       % push second input again
100*V    % multiply by 100 and convert to string
37h      % append the '%' symbol to it
yn2/k    % compute half of the length of the output array
yny+q    % copy of that + length of the 'N%' string - 1
         % stack: [[61;61;61;...;0;0;0], '15%', 38, 40]
&:       % make a range from the first to the second (38 to 40)
(        % assign the 'N%' string at those places into the output array
91w93    % surround by '[' (ASCII 91) and ']' (93) characters
v!       % combine into a single array, make it horizontal for display, 
c        % change it to character type (implicitly displayed)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 108*.75 = 81 bytes

A function that takes input from `[A1]` and `[B1]` and outputs to the console

```vb
s=""&[MID(IFERROR(REPT("",A1*B1),"")&REPT("",A1),2,A1-2)]&"":n=100*[B1]:Mid(s,([A1]-len(n))/2)=n &"%":?s
```

#### Output

with input `[A1]=25` and `[B1]=.76`

```vb
76%
```

With input `[A1:B1].Resize(1,2)=Split("32 -.5")`

```vb
-50%
```

With input `[A1:B1].Resize(1,2)=Split("40 10.01")`

```vb
1001%
```